# Brower fixed point theorem vs conformal maps

Tags: complex-analysis, fixed-point-theorems

I was reading a proof of the following theorem.

If $U$ is the open unit disc in $\mathbb{C}$, and $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ is analytic, then $d(f(x),f(z))<d(x,z)$ if $x\not=z$ (here $d$ is the hyperbolic metric). Also, if $\sup_{x\in U}|f(x)|<1$, then $f$ is a contraction and has a fixed point, since $(U,d)$ is a complete metric space.

This is an application of the Banach contraction mapping theorem, but I was wondering if one could also argue that since $\sup_{x\in U}|f(x)|=\delta<1$, we have that $B_{\delta}(0)\subset\mathbb{C}$ (the closed ball) and $f$ restricted to this set maps $f:B_{\delta}(0)\to B_{\delta}(0)$. Then since $f$ is continuous, it has a fixed point by Brower fixed point theorem.

Is this correct? I was wondering that it might not be because it would perhaps make the argument using the hyperbolic space less interesting. But maybe it's that the Banach contraction theorem is easy to prove, whereas the Brower fixed point theorem is hard to prove, so maybe you have to make up for this in the hyperbolic argument with some additional theorems about analytic maps. Any thoughts?

Comment: Does $B_\delta(0)$ refer to an open disc?

Comment: Sorry, it's the closed ball of radius $\delta$

Comment: This is correct and it is also true that proof of  Brower FPT is much more difficult than CMT. So this proof is not interesting in my opnion.

Comment: This is correct, and a quick proof. Nice job. Do note that Brouwer's Fixed Point Theorem is nonconstructive in the sense that there is no way in general to figure out where the fixed point will be, while Banach's Fixed Point Theorem is constructive in the sense that it provides a limiting process that converges to a fixed point.